# How to determine the correct size to set a JLabel to if it's going to be initialized later to a known String

Tags: java, swing, size, jlabel

I have a JLabel which at creation is going to be blank.
Later it's going to be initialized to a string "Hello World"

If I setText to "Hello World" later on, my whole layout gets screwed up (FWIW, I am using GridBagLayout).

This is the only way I found to avoid this issue.

```
JLabel tmp = new JLabel("Hello World");
Dimension d = tmp.getPreferredSize();

JLabel actual = new JLabel();
actual.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Is there no better way to do this?

Comment: since it's a label ... have you tried setVisible?

Comment: @Stultuske: sorry, but that's a ridiculous suggestion. @ The original poster, I don't know of a straightforward one-size-fits all solution. You could of course fill the JLabel with spaces, `"          "`, but you'd have to guess what would be the best size prior to knowing what text will be inserted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels filling with spaces will work only for fixed width fonts.

Comment: You could extend JLabel and override its `getPreferredSize` such that it never gets smaller than the size it would have with some minimal text.

Comment: @user93353 there no issue to get Dimension in pixels from Font and String, 3-4 methods in different AWT/Swing APIs

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - why do I need to extend for that - I can just call setPreferredSize- but my question is what do I set the preferred size as - the question remains even if I extend JLabel

Comment: filling with spaces will work only for fixed width fonts. != true, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable,

Comment: Use a JTextField, set to the number of characters you, strip out the border, make it transparent and non-editable

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there any advantage of doing that over my current method of using a temporary JLabel?

Comment: @user93353 have you tried to revalidate your panel after setting text of label? Somthing like this: `label.getRootPane().revalidate()` and `label.getRootPane().repaint()`

Comment: @user93353 It lets the system make the decisions for you and you're not creating temporary objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the full context of the question? Why is it so important if the size changes? Does the change in size affect the grid of the GridBagLayout?

Maybe you need a better design of the form so that a changing size in the text of the label does not affect the layout of the other components on the form? That is, maybe you need to nest different panels with different layout managers.

For example you could use a panel with a CardLayout and then have each label as a card for the panel. Then instead of changing the text, you swap the labels. This way the panel will reserve the space for the largest card in the layout.